# How to display 0 if the count of distinct values is null?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

My table has **X** distinct vendors,each of those vendors has **Y** objectives (including none)

```
vendor varchar2(100),
location varchar2(100),
type varchar2(100),
rating varchar2(20),
control_objective varchar2(1000)
```

now I need to display a bar graph that runs on the following script

```
select trim(vendor)||' '||trim(location)||' '||trim(type1) AS vendor_location,
       count(distinct control_objective) as "Cont Obj" 
from some_table
where (Rating = 'Needs improvement' or Rating = 'Unacceptable') and 
      "Year" = '2011' and 
      Quarter = 'Q3'
group by trim(vendor)||' '||trim(location)||' '||trim(type1)
order by trim(vendor)||' '||trim(location)||' '||trim(type1);
```

and produces the following output

```
-----vendor_location----Cont Obj
1----Big Blue Car---------5
2----Big Red Car----------4
3----Small Pink Truck-----4
4----Small White Truck----2
```

The problem is, there might be a **5th** vendor, say **Big White Van** which has no values in the objective field hence it is not displayed. But I want it to be displayed as follows.

```
-----vendor_location----Cont Obj
1----Big Blue Car---------5
2----Big Red Car----------4
3----Small Pink Truck-----4
4----Small White Truck----2
5----Big White Van--------0
```

Reason being, the script feeds values into a bar graph, so I need the value 0 on the graph. I've tried several ways of overcoming this which is posted below

```
select trim(vendor)||' '||trim(location)||' '||trim(type1) AS vendor_location,
       count(distinct nvl(control_objective,0)) as "Cont Obj" 
from some_table
where (Rating = 'Needs improvement' or Rating = 'Unacceptable') and 
      "Year" = '2011' and 
      Quarter = 'Q3'
group by trim(vendor)||' '||trim(location)||' '||trim(type1)
order by trim(vendor)||' '||trim(location)||' '||trim(type1);
```

and

```
select trim(vendor)||' '||trim(location)||' '||trim(type1) AS vendor_location,
       (count(distinct control_objective)+0) as "Cont Obj" from some_table
where (Rating = 'Needs improvement' or Rating = 'Unacceptable') and 
      "Year" = '2011' and 
      Quarter = 'Q3'
group by trim(vendor)||' '||trim(location)||' '||trim(type1)
order by trim(vendor)||' '||trim(location)||' '||trim(type1);
```

and

```
select trim(vendor)||' '||trim(location)||' '||trim(type1) AS vendor_location,
       case when (count(distinct control_objective)<1) 
            then 0 
            else count(distinct control_objective) 
       end as "Cont Obj" 
from some_table
where (Rating = 'Needs improvement' or Rating = 'Unacceptable') and 
      "Year" = '2011' and 
      Quarter = 'Q3'
group by trim(vendor)||' '||trim(location)||' '||trim(type1)
order by trim(vendor)||' '||trim(location)||' '||trim(type1);
```

All the above attempts gave me the same output as I got earlier.

Honestly, I can't think of any more ways. The **last option** I have is to write the output into a table, and manually enter the missing values and then display the table. But this is really not what I want because the script should work for future quarters and years. So in the future some other value may be null and writing and reading into a table defeats the purpose of being "future-proof" so basically its not an option, just a quick-fix for the coming deadline.

I am using **SQL Developer** to test the scripts and the database is **Oracle 11g**

P.S. If it is not possible, do let me know. I'm even open to that being an answer!! I don't have much experience with SQL.

**EDIT**

Thank you all. I realised my problem on the way back home. The rating condition was not being satisfied, but couldn't post it until I got back home. Big thanks to Marcin!

Comment: Does your table have record for "Big white van"? What is the rating, year, quarter value for that row?

Comment: Will all vendors (including those with no control objectives) have entries on some_table for the desired year and quarter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should see 'Big White Van' if it is in the table and the other fields (Rating , Year, Quarter) fulfill your condition. I guess you rather need something like this:

```
select trim(vendor) || ' ' || trim(location) || ' ' || trim(type1) AS vendor_location,
       count(distinct case
               when (Rating = 'Needs improvement' or Rating = 'Unacceptable') and "Year" = '2011' and Quarter = 'Q3' then
                control_objective
               else
                null
             end) as "Cont Obj"
  from some_table
 group by trim(vendor) || ' ' || trim(location) || ' ' || trim(type1)
 order by trim(vendor) || ' ' || trim(location) || ' ' || trim(type1);
```

which means: give me all vendor_locations and for each show me count of distinct control_objective values from those records for which (Rating = 'Needs improvement' or Rating = 'Unacceptable') and "Year" = '2011' and Quarter = 'Q3'

Comment: Yes, it does have values for everything and on my way back home I realised that it is not meeting the rating criteria (rating is 'Acceptable') But I still need to show that value. I'm thinking of something else, will post it as an edit! Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's not appearing is not because the value is null, it's because it's not fulfilling some other condition. Check that.

```
SELECT a, COUNT(DISTINCT b)
FROM (
    SELECT 'a' a, 'b' b FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'b', NULL FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'b', NULL FROM dual
)
GROUP BY a

->

b - 0
a - 1
```

Comment: Thank you, I realised my problem!! Was so blind!